# Can i store the unspecified type in GtkListStore?

Tags: c++, c, gtk

Can i store the unspecified type in GtkListStore? For instance, I want to store in one field - the field of int type and the field of GdkColor type ?

Comment: could you please clarify your question.

Comment: I have already GtkListStore with 3 fields. The 1st field is "leftRange" of double type. The 2nd field is "rightRange" of double type too. But 3 field is "properties". And I want that this field can be define as unspecified type and can be int type, GdkColor type and etc.. You understand me, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me asked that It will be set the G_TYPE_VALUE type of field

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkListStore* store = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_VALUE);
  GValue v = { 0 };
  GtkTreeIter iter;
  gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
  g_value_init(&v, G_TYPE_INT);
  g_value_set_int(&v, 10);
  GValue gv = { 0 };
  g_value_init(&gv, G_TYPE_VALUE);
  g_value_set_boxed(&gv, &v);
  gtk_list_store_set_value(store, &iter, 0, &gv);

  GValue gv2 = { 0 };
  gtk_tree_model_get_value((GtkTreeModel*)store, &iter, 0, &gv2);
  printf("gv2 holds %s\n", g_type_name(G_VALUE_TYPE(&gv2)));
  GValue * gv3 = (GValue*)g_value_get_boxed(&gv2);
  printf("gv3 holds %s\n", g_type_name(G_VALUE_TYPE(gv3)));

  int int_v = g_value_get_int(gv3);
  printf("int_v = %d\n", int_v);

  return 0;
}
```

I have followed this example from https://gist.github.com/867930

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [unions in C C++](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-structures-and-unions.html)